# Can I write the integral of a function in terms of its level sets?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

I have a function like this $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}_+$

$$f(x, y) = e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$$

Its level sets $f(x, y) = c$ are simply circles centered at the origin
$$
x^2 + y^2 = \log\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\right) \qquad \forall\, c\in\mathbb{R}_+
$$

[image]

Here's my question:

> Usually we would take the integral of this function as a double integral where one dimension of integration is $x$ and one is $y$
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x, y) dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) dx dy 
> $$
> Can we rewrite this integral as an integral over its level sets? For instance something like this
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x, y) dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \int_{x^2 + y^2 = \log\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\right)} f(x, y) dt dc
> $$

I am not sure how to write it and I am pretty sure the "inner" integral should be modified so that we are integrating in a "curvilinear" way along the circle.

Comment: Well, yes, but that amounts to integrating in polar coordinates.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you for your comment! Okay maybe I wrote down an example that is a bit too simple. In practice the contours could be ellipses or any other shape really. I was hoping there would be a general result (assuming some sort of smoothness of the level sets of course)

Comment: Of course. Then you might be interested in the "coarea formula".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you! Would you mind writing an answer to exemplify how to use it in this case?

Comment: Well, right now I am using a cellphone, so I cannot write anything complex. My intuition here is that you don't really use the coarea formula in practice. That's more for theoretical applications. In practice, you build a coordinate system adapted to your level sets and then you change variables, computing the Jacobian of the coordinate change. The coarea formula is just the abstract systematization of this concrete procedure.

Comment: Oh wow! I tried to wrap my head around the co-area formula for a bit but I never understood it. Your explanation already makes so much sense! So would that be related to putting a coordinate system on a manifold? Where the manifold would be the level set in this case. Also, please do take your time, an answer using the co-area formula would really help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way, it's something called a [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration). Assuming that $f(x,y) > 0$ we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^\infty \mu\big(\{(x,y): f(x,y) > t\}\big) dt $$

where $\mu(A)$ is generally called the Lebesgue measure of a set, and in the case of 'nice' sets it's just the area; in this case, the area of the region where $f(x,y) > t$.

With the function $f(x,y) = e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$ we have:
\begin{align}\{(x,y): f(x,y) > t\} &= \{(x,y): e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} > t\} = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2 <  - 2 \ln t\} =\\
&= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \varnothing & \text{for }t\ge 1 \\ \{(x,y): x^2+y^2 <  2 |\ln t|\} & \text{for }0<t< 1\end{array} \right. \end{align}
so
$$ \mu\big(\{(x,y): f(x,y) > t\}\big) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{for }t\ge 1 \\ 2\pi| \ln t| & \text{for }0<t< 1\end{array} \right.$$
and you get

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^1 2\pi| \ln t| dt = 2\pi(t-t\ln t)\big|_0^1 =2\pi$$

The Lebesgue integral can be defined on other sets, not only $\mathbb R^n$, as long as you can measure the size of sets somehow.

ANOTHER APPROACH:

Another way you can try to calculate this integral is to parametrize $\mathbb R^2$ with new coordinates $x= x(c,t)$, $y=y(c,t)$ such that
$$ f(x(c,t),y(c,t)) = c$$
Then we have
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dx dy = \iint f(x(c,t),y(c,t)) |J(c,t)| dc dt = \iint c |J(c,t)| dc dt$$
where $J(c,t)$ is the jacobian:
$$ J(c,t) = \det\left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial x}{\partial c}& \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial c}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{array}\right]$$

In this case, we could use coordinates $(c,t)$ such that $c\in(0,1]$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and
$$ x= \sqrt{-2\ln c} \cos t$$
$$ y= \sqrt{-2\ln c} \sin t$$
Then
$$ |J(c,t)| = \frac{1}{c} $$
so
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dx dy = \iint_{(c,t)\in(0,1]\times[0,2\pi]} c \frac{1}{c} dc dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\int_0^1 dc\Big) dt = 2\pi $$
In this case, the integral turns out to be very simple, but in general it's difficult to find parametrization $x= x(c,t)$, $y=y(c,t)$. This case was special because the level sets were concentric circles, so just a slight modification of well-known radial coordinates did the job.

Comment: Thank you! I have a few questions but first.. is this a general result/definition? And do you know where I could see similar examples with level sets?

Comment: Yes, every-Riemann-integrable function can be rewritten as a Lebesgue integral, although sometimes you may obtain some weird sets that you may not be sure how to measure. Even some functions that are not Riemann-integrable can be integrated using the Lebesgue integral. For details, look up the Lebesgue measure and the linked wiki page for the Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Thank you! I have found something called the [Co-Area Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) but I struggle to understand the notation. If you know about it, do you think it could be related to this?

Comment: Yes, it can be used, but in this application it just becomes the change of variables. Added explenation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Does that mean that when we write $(x, y) = (x(c, t), y(c, t))$ then $c$ determines which level-set we are on while $t$ determines the position within that level-set?

Comment: Also how can $\sqrt{-2\ln(c)}$ exist? Surely $-2\ln(c)$ can be negative for some $c$!

Comment: If $f(x(c,t),y(c,t))=c$ then yes, $c$ is the coordinate that distinguishes level sets. In general, $x(c,t),y(c,t)$ may be an arbitrary coordinate change and $c$ may be unrelated to the level sets, but then we cannot simplify $$ \iint f(x(c,t),y(c,t)) |J(c,t)| dc dt = \iint c |J(c,t)| dc dt$$

And if $c\in(0,1]$ (as was the range of $c$ defined), then $-\ln c>0$

Comment: Oh right! Makes so much sense since the maximum value the function can take is $e^0 = 1$

Comment: I am very curious about your last comment. What if I have a parametrization $x(\alpha, \beta)$ and $y(\alpha, \beta)$ where, say, $\beta = \beta(c)$ is a function of the level set value?

Comment: It's not a problem. You can use any parametrization you want, as long as you properly calculate the Jacobian $J(\alpha,\beta)$ and value of the function $f(x(\alpha,\beta),y(\alpha,\beta))$. You can se any change of variables to transform the integral, it's not even relevant whether they are related to level sets or not, as long as they parametrize the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: But in general, if I wanted to write the integral in terms of the level sets, would I always be able to use your method or the co-area formula?

Comment: I think that maybe $u^{-1}(t)$ in the co-area formula on wikipedia could represent the level set

$$
f^{-1}(t) = \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\, :\, x^2 + y^2 = \log\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\right)\right\}
$$

Is this correct? If this is not always correct, how would one make sure this happens?

Comment: In the co-area formula you can choose $u$ and $g$ independently. So yes, you can choose it like as well.