# L1 distance between functions and integral of symmetric difference between sublevel sets

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have come across this question : [Can I write the integral of a function in terms of its level sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063958/can-i-write-the-integral-of-a-function-in-terms-of-its-level-sets) and it makes me wonder if the L1 distance between $f$ and $g$, two bounded function over a compact (let say $[0,1]^{n}$ for simplicity) can be written in terms of the Lebesgue measure (denoted $L$) of the symmetric difference between $f^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[)$ and $g^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[)$.

More precisely, does the following expression holds ? :

$$\int_{[0,1]^{n}}|f(x)-g(x)|dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}L(f^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[)\Delta g^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[))d\lambda$$

I think that i have a proof using some Fubini's theorems (as we work on a compact and $f$ and $g$ are bounded) but may be I have made a mistake manipulating integrals without enough caution and it require stronger conditions.

Also, I wonder if the compactness assumption and the "boundedness" assumption are necessary ?